# Повышение производительности DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

За счет чего можно достигнуть высокой производительности в DataTable при поиске в ней?

Есть ли какие-то аналоги индексов или ограничений, которые позволят искать быстрее?

Comment: PrimaryKey плохо работает? Если id уникально - можно PrimaryKey (свойство) добавить столбец, и по нему поднимать строку.

Comment: А какие у вас юзкейсы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы предложил вовсе не искать в `DataTable`. Хороший подход, как мне кажется, чтение данных в фоновым потоке, выборка данных из них в список типизированных структур и поиск уже там. Для ускорения — построение нужных индексов (в простейшем случае — просто `Dictionary<string, Entity>`).

(Ну и вообще, мне кажется, что `DataTable` хороша для приложений, выглядящих [так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY6QJ.gif), а не [так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYkW5.jpg).)

Comment: Т.е лучше вместо чтения голых DataRow, лучше их затолкать в какой-нибудь класс и обернуть в List? А есть разница между чтением DataReader и прогоном через foreach?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Ну, быстрее прогона по списку, а ещё плюс индексация, не бывает. Если DataTable медленный, то он делает что-то не так. Плюс вы наверняка хотите показывать не содержимое таблицы с ID и ForeinKey, а нормальные данные.

Comment: хм... Действительно. Использование словаря свело 5 минут преобразований, до нескольких секунд. А ведь я на DataTable пааллельный LINQ натравливал, а тут и без него все в шоколаде.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Вот видите, подходящие структуры данных часто решают задачу намного лучше, чем параллелизация и использование мощности процессора.

Answer (score -1):

Хранимые процедуры и DataReader

Comment: А, можете, написать более развёрнутый ответ?